# Why Blazor wasm project did not load on IOS on a iPAd and iPhone

Tags: ios, safari, mono, blazor, blazor-client-side

Loading the default demo project works well on win10 with google chrome and firefox, also
on Mac with Safari but it just come up with a "loading ..." message on IOS (iPad and iPhone).

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Blazor wasm has some issues with iOS 13 at the moment. See this thread for some workarounds and to keep up to date with it: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/16986

In particular, you have to add `<script>var Module;</script>` before the blazor.webassembly.js script in your index.html.

Then you want to copy the blazor.webassembly.js file and make a custom version and apply these changes:
[image]
[image]

These issues will hopefully be fixed in an upcoming version.